# Rename Files in a Zip derived from Mac

Tags: c#, macos, zip

I have an application to unzip .Zip, .rar and .7zip files.

However I am faced with a problem, when a mac user sends a zip with files whose names contain for example "**:**" this crashes my application which is quite normal because Windows does not accept this kind of element in the name of a file.

In short, Apple ...

After some tests, I realized that we could change the name of the files in the archive using **Winrar**.

So do you have any idea how I can change the name of the files in the archive before extracting it (in C#) ?

I tried ZipArchive but it crashes because it is intended for Windows so quite normal.

Thank's in advance ;)

Comment: Use code at following links.  The ExractTo accepts two paramters.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.compression.zipfile.open?view=net-5.0 and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.compression.zipfile.extracttodirectory?view=net-5.0

Comment: We'll need a [mcve] of your progress so far.